# SSH and remove files with pattern rm -r /path/to/files/!(zz-*.log) in Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, rm

I am running into issues running the following command from my jenkins file.

```
sh "ssh ${user}@${server} rm -r /path/to/files/!(zz-*.log)"
```

The error produced in the console is as follows

`line 2: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

I have tried several permutations of quotes and character escaping, but still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is not answering your specific question, since i hate dealing with escaping bash commands in Jenkinsfiles too, but it's another way around it. and it's a way where you don't have to worry about maintaining a script with quadruple-escaped quotes! :) set up what you'll need as environment variables (`SSH_USER` and `SSH_TARGET_SERVER` maybe) and put this command in a bash script instead of your Jenkinsfile. in fact, put your entire ci process in a shell script and just call that from jenkins if you can. this keeps your ci process portable, in case you want to switch off jenkins in the future for some reason.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_TARGET_SERVER} rm -r /path/to/files/!(zz-*.log)
```